# Login With Another SQL Server in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-authentication

I have 5 projects which are successfully deployed.... i need to give access to the user by single login to all these projects...

For example : I have 5 web app seprately which are deployed as

```
https://example.com/project1
https://example.com/project2
https://example.com/project3
https://example.com/project4
https://example.com/project5
```

and have their separate sql...

```
I need to login the user at very first and then the user can access all these web app and their working should go on with their respective sql....
```

these projects are created on laravel so, Right now the laravel auth is working and they have their own login system

**All i need is to login user once and they can access all these apps**

and user should login with 6th SQL(means another SQL)

Comment: what you need is a some form of single sign on (sso). you can try oauth as laravel fortify have them out of the box.

Answer (score -1):

In same situation, i made one more project only for authentification with Laravel Passport and add this project as socialite provider to other applications.

With this flow you have one entry point and user management for all projects.

**First** - make auth project. You need Laravel and Laravel Passport. See docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/passport). Optional - make user management ui (adding, removing, etc). **Goal - users can login with their login/password.**

**Second** - add ability to login for other projects with `laravel/socialite`.

- Install `laravel/socialite` and `socialiteproviders/manager`
- Create your own provider for your auth project - to example see the [docs](https://github.com/SocialiteProviders/Manager#creating-a-provider) in `socialiteproviders/manager`
- Implement LoginController in your apps for socialite. Some example:

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    // Custom service for work with socialite - create or find users, etc
    private SocialiteService $service;

    public function __construct(SocialiteService $service)
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except(['logout', 'callback']);
        $this->service = $service;
    }

    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        return view('pages.login');
    }

    public function login()
    {
        return $this->service->redirectToAuth();
    }

    public function callback(Request $request)
    {
        try{
            $user = $this->service->getUser($request);
            auth()->login($user);
            return redirect()->route('index');
        }catch (SocialiteException $exception){
            return redirect()->route('login')->withErrors([
                'error' => $exception->getMessage(),
                'error_description' => $exception->getErrorDescription()
            ]);
        }
    }

    public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        auth()->logout();
        $request->session()->invalidate();
        $request->session()->regenerateToken();
        return redirect()->route('login');
    }
}
```

And after that you have SSO for all your apps with dedicated auth service.

Hint: create a private package with provider, service and all you auth logic. With this you can simply add this auth flow to feature projects and avoid duplicated code.